# Healthcheck of SpringBoot service in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab-ci, health-check, spring-actuator, gitlab-pipelines

I have a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline which:

- builds Spring Boot app
- packages it to a Docker image
- deploy the image using `docker run ...`

I'd like to be able to validate the service after deployment. I want to be informed by the pipeline about the failure. I guess I need an additional *healthcheck* step in the pipeline to validate the service.

Is there any best practices for this task? Is there any ready to use solutions?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to implement the check using **spring actuator** + `curl` + `grep`.

The pipeline:

```yaml
check-spring-actuator-health:
  image: curlimages/curl
  stage: Health Ckeck
  script:
# exit with error if actuator/health doesn't return 'UP'
    - curl $ACTUATOR_HEALTH_URL | grep "{\"status\":\"UP\"}" || ( echo Helth Check Failed Actuator=$ACTUATOR_HEALTH_URL && exit 2; )
```

This step fails it the actruator/health URL isn't available or returns anything but `{"status":"UP"}`